# How can i display time as '5 minute ago', 'yesterday' etc in android

Tags: android

I have stored time in milliseconds in android SQLite database. Now, I want to display it as messaging application displays time e.g. '5 minute ago' etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use following code:

```
    private String calculateRelativeTime(long time) {

        String relativetime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time).toString();
        return relativetime;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution, int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29)